# React: same component reappearing multiple times in the app, how can I make sure that all states are captured accurately and not just the last?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an app where the user can type in a number and make as many - we will call them "mini-forms" - they want via the `Add a Plus Content Line` and then on the `Generate Plus Content` button click it should be outputted in the `textarea` of `OutputDiv` to then be copy and pasted elsewhere (later stored in a database).

However, I have run into a snag where, I cannot figure out how to have the state hold all the data present in the "mini-forms", only the data of the last updated state. I'm trying to hold an array of states, rather than just one state.

I think the fiddle is the best demo of what I am trying to achieve

The flow of data is as follows: `TitleDiv` -> `PlusContent` -> `PlusContentHolder` -> `PlusContentForm` -> `App` -> `OutputDiv`

Fiddle to demonstrate what I mean : https://jsfiddle.net/4hpbj53t/1/

One thing is, I have left the expected output logged in the console, rather than in the `OutputDiv`, because the console.log demonstrates that only my last state is carried through.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, as I am still learning react :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way, but it seems a much more Javascript way and seems to ignore many of the things which make react worth using, such an not directly interacting with the DOM:
In the fiddle this will be placed in the `PlusContentHolder` part

```
const titleInfoHandler = (x) => {
    let titleArray = [];
    let allTerms = {};

    document.getElementsByName("title").forEach((title) =>{
      titleArray.push(title.value)
   })

   for(let i = 0; i < titleArray.length; i++){
     allTerms[i] = {...allTerms[i], title: titleArray[i]}
   }

    setPlusContent((prevState) => {
      return{...prevState, titleArray}})
   props.titlePointer(plusContent)
  };
```

I am still looking for a better way, as I have more than just a title input in this component, so any feedback, criticism etc. would be appreciated :)